Zoom client continually "crashes" even though uninstalled
I installed the Ubuntu Zoom client from a .deb file. In the first meeting, it crashed, and I had to restart the client. During that same first meeting, it kept popping up with notifications saying it had crashed.
I don't use zoom a lot, so I uninstalled it. It still "crashes" about every 5-10 minutes. I keep getting a dialog pop-up (two at a time) telling me it crashed. I've searched for zoom files on the machine, and deleted them. I've restarted. I don't know what to do.
Ubuntu: Jammy (22.04.4)
Zoom: None (was latest as of 2 weeks ago).

What is causing this pop-up to continue?

EDIT: As per a comment, here is the output of locate Zoom (which I already had installed) and plocate Zoom
% locate Zoom
/etc/brltty/Input/bm/NLS_Zoomax.ktb
/home/cwverica/.zoom/data/ZoomAppIcon
/home/cwverica/Android/Sdk/sources/android-34/android/widget/ZoomButton.java
/home/cwverica/Android/Sdk/sources/android-34/android/widget/ZoomButtonsController.java
/home/cwverica/Android/Sdk/sources/android-34/android/widget/ZoomControls.java
/home/cwverica/git/modelbuilder/src/features/app/components/ZoomButton.js
/home/cwverica/git/modelbuilder/src/features/app/components/ZoomToolUI.js
/snap/core/17200/usr/lib/python3.5/idlelib/ZoomHeight.py
/snap/core/17200/usr/lib/python3.5/idlelib/__pycache__/ZoomHeight.cpython-35.pyc
/snap/gimp/436/usr/share/gimp/2.0/fractalexplorer/Zooming_Circle
/snap/gimp/436/usr/share/gtk-doc/html/libgimp/GimpZoomPreview.html
/snap/gimp/436/usr/share/gtk-doc/html/libgimpwidgets/GimpZoomModel.html
/usr/share/yelp/mathjax/extensions/MathZoom.js



% plocate Zoom
/etc/brltty/Input/bm/NLS_Zoomax.ktb
/home/cwverica/.zoom/data/ZoomAppIcon
/home/cwverica/Android/Sdk/sources/android-34/android/widget/ZoomButton.java
/home/cwverica/Android/Sdk/sources/android-34/android/widget/ZoomButtonsController.java
/home/cwverica/Android/Sdk/sources/android-34/android/widget/ZoomControls.java
/home/cwverica/git/modelbuilder/src/features/app/components/ZoomButton.js
/home/cwverica/git/modelbuilder/src/features/app/components/ZoomToolUI.js
/snap/core/17200/usr/lib/python3.5/idlelib/ZoomHeight.py
/snap/core/17200/usr/lib/python3.5/idlelib/__pycache__/ZoomHeight.cpython-35.pyc
/snap/gimp/436/usr/share/gimp/2.0/fractalexplorer/Zooming_Circle
/snap/gimp/436/usr/share/gtk-doc/html/libgimp/GimpZoomPreview.html
/snap/gimp/436/usr/share/gtk-doc/html/libgimpwidgets/GimpZoomModel.html
/usr/share/yelp/mathjax/extensions/MathZoom.js


We need to find what are the traces of zoom left. Install plocate. sudo apt install plocate. Now update database sudo updatedb. Now, enter the command locate Zoom, and post the output by editing the question. Edit link https://askubuntu.com/posts/1525407/edit

Looks like you somehow installed Android SDK, then installed Zoom into that Android environment. Apt doesn't know anything about the Android environment you created. Use Android tools to uninstall Zoom from that environment.

I have the android sdk because I'm tinkering around and learning. I'm fairly certain that the three files are for zoom controls (e.g. zooming in and out) that come standard. Trust me, this sorting has been a pain. I think the only Zoom (application) related file here is the ZoomAppIcon

Have you restarted the computer since uninstalling zoom?

Can you also please add the output of locate zoom? (not Zoom)?

@ArchismanPanigrahi this has helped. There is a whole folder ~/.zoom of what looks like links, as it's only 8 units (~4kb) in size, but has subfolders with ~1000 entries. Apart from that there hundreds of entries seeming to relate to zooming in and out. However, there are also these two entries: /var/lib/dpkg/info/zoom.list and
/var/lib/dpkg/info/zoom.postrm Should those be removed as well?

Instead of deleting them one by one, can you try running the command sudo apt remove zoom?

The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libwpe-1.0-1 libwpebackend-fdo-1.0-1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 27 not upgraded.```

I deleted the ~/.zoom folder, as well as the other two files mentioned, and that seems to have cleared it up. Thank you so much.

The solution was deleting a few files left over on the machine.

The entire hidden folder ~/.zoom
/var/lib/dpkg/info/zoom.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/zoom.postrm
/var/crash/_opt_on_zoom_1000.crash

